# Importing Calendar events from iCloud IOS

Tags: ios, swift, calendar, icloud

Hi i have researched regarding importing calendar events from iCloud. Some of the sites are suggesting EventKit framework but will EventKit framework provide events which are saved on iCloud?

There is option to get events from Calendar app in iPhone but need events saved on iCloud.

Comment: Why do you think that events (regardless whether they are backed up by iCloud) wouldn't be reachable using EventKit? iCloud data related to any app is not directly available.

Comment: Because google also provide the api..

We can access google calendars using this api

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/ios?ver=swift

Comment: It is not API dedicated to events in Calendar App. It is API to get to 3rd party data/service.

Comment: Ok so is there something available with iCloud?